# SQL Exception occured?

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form_sign_in_

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=TAYYAB-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Hospital Management;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;User=sa;Pwd=Password1;")
    Dim SQL As New SQL_Control


    Private Sub Form_sign_in__Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
            MsgBox("Succesfully connected! ")
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Sub Executequery(query As String)

        Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)

        connection.Open()


> **command.ExecuteNonQuery()**// the problem part

        connection.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Insertquery As String = "INSERT INTO Patient Information

           (F_Name , L_Name, Patient ID, Disease, First Visit, Last Visit) VALUES ( ' " & TextBox2.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox3.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox4.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox5.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox6.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox7.Text & " ' ,)"

        Executequery(Insertquery)

        MsgBox("Data Inserted")

    End Sub


End Class
```

The problem is there:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near
>   'Information'.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4KN9.jpg]

Anyone knows the solution I am Stuck with a problem in my project

Answer (score 1):

Is your table name really “Patient Information” with a space?

If so try adding [ ] around it. Also, add these round “Patient ID”,”First Visit” and “Last Visit”

Failing that. Try running the query in SSMS and replace the textbox.texts with manually entered strings.

SSMS should tell you anything wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0):

In "Insertquery" you use a comma (`,`) - remove that.

Try this

```
Dim cmd as new sqlcommand("INSERT INTO [Patient Information](F_Name ,L_Name, Patient ID, Disease, First Visit, Last Visit) VALUES ( ' " & TextBox2.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox3.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox4.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox5.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox6.Text & " ' , ' " & TextBox7.Text & " ' ,con")
```

for executing the the command connection is required.

in your program, remove the comma in the sqlcommand.

Comment: can you give the screen shot? for better understanding.